# What is the earliest science fictional or fantastical example of a woman being sterilised to take on new power?

Tags: history-of

A recent example comes from *The Witcher*, whilst I believe it is true of the books, we get an explicit backstory to Yennefer in the TV series and we witness her transformation that makes her sterile.

> **Yennefer:** Leave my eyes. These as well.
>
> **Giltine:** There is a cost to all creation. A sacrifice that is always made. To be reborn... you will bear no more. Do you understand? Good.
>
> <sub>*The Witcher*, Season 1 Episode 3, "Betrayer Moon"</sub>

To a lesser extent we see this in the Marvel Cinematic Universe with Black Widow, Natasha Romanoff, who is sterilised at the end of her training in the Red Room.

> **Natasha Romanoff:** In the Red Room, where I was trained, where I was raised, they have a graduation ceremony. They sterilize you. It's efficient. One less thing to worry about. The one thing that might matter more than a mission. Makes everything easier, even killing.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Age of Ultron*</sub>

But what is the earliest science fictional or fantastical example of a woman being sterilised to take on new power?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is just a continuation of the mythology of the virgin priestess.

Comment: @Valorum Probably so, but mythology wouldn't be an answer of course.

Comment: I have two cases of immortality, simply because TV Tropes has an entry for Immortal Procreation Clause where immortality means you can't have kids. My apologies if that is not what you are looking for.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Sounds like it should match, I'm using "power" pretty loosely. In general looking for someone trading their ability to have children for something else. In the most basic of sense.

Comment: Ah, and I've found that one of them was not a case of immortality causing infertility, but rather not preventing it, so I deleted that answer.

Comment: This one will likely take some digging; the "price" for power being loss of X (In this case fertility) reaches back to medieval lore and possibly further back than that.  It is not a recent idea. I am not sure if philologists will be of assistance, but Joseph Campbell's works on stories and story telling across various cultural boundaries may be a place to look.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot: Are you referring to the ability to have children *by any means* or just the ability to have children the female way?  Because I've got an example of losing the latter but not the former.

Comment: @jwodder Talking about females and by having children the normal biological way.

Comment: Why would mythology not be an answer..?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Mythology is in a grey area whether it’s on topic or not. Some is, some isn’t. Safer to generally exclude it in my opinion.

Comment: Are you only looking for female specific examples?  Or would gender nonspecific or male  specific examples also work?

Comment: Regarding your Witcher example, this is NOT true to the books. In the books it is common for sorcerers to be sterile due to a dysfunction of the pituary gland and other bodily changes caused by magic. However some are fertile and can procreate. Tissaia de Vries argues in the books that every apprentice should be sterilized as no one should be born a wizard. There is no power to be gained from this process, it is merely her opinion, that every person should decide to be a wizard or a parent, not both. The whole turn sterile to gain power plot point is an invention of the show.

Comment: @Dulkan Thanks for the correction, I've only read _The Last Wish_ so am yet to get into all the details of the story proper.

Answer (score 52):

In Shakespeare's *Macbeth* (1606), Lady Macbeth calls on evil spirits to "unsex" her, giving her the supernaturally-charged determination to go through with the murder of Duncan:

> Come, you spirits
> That tend on mortal thoughts, unsex me here
> and fill me from the crown to the toe topful
> Of direst cruelty. Make thick my blood
> Stop up th'accents and passage to remorse,
> that no compunctious visitings of nature
> Shake my fell purpose, nor keep peace between
> Th'effect and it. Come to my woman's breasts
> And take my milk for gall, you murdering ministers...

This renunciation of her traditional womanhood is drawn from contemporary beliefs that witches' bodies were tainted by their association with dark powers. That includes the ideas that her blood would not flow properly, that she would have unusual marks on her body, etc.

This is not necessarily fully "fantastical" since it's based in a belief that this sort of thing *really happened*, but it is a pretty clear antecedent to the other examples presented: Lady Macbeth gives up fertility in order to gain power, in a classic magical-style exchange. The cultural weight of Shakespeare on following writers is also pretty considerable.

Comment: Damn, answering the question by pulling something from 400 years ago AND bringing up Shakespear? +1

Comment: I had that same answer and did delete it, because I was under the impression that the question was about superpowers (which she did not get), not political power.  Despite involvement with the supernatural, Lady Macbeth did not turn into a witch (or super trained assassin) herself, she merely nudged an insecure husband and then went mad.

Comment: Your interpretation of ‘unsex me’ is different than the one I have in my mind; I had pictured it as Lady M. asking the spirits to make her a man, basically, so that she’d have the courage, strength, whatever men had that women didn’t according to the sexist policies of the time, to carry out what she planned to do. But I’ll bow to your wisdom, if you have a reference.

Comment: @EikePierstorff Since OP mentioned Black Widow, who basically gained the same thing as Lady Macbeth, I think this answer works just fine

Answer (score 8):

This may be stretching the definition of "sterilize" a bit, but consider the 1967 novel *Lord of Light* by Roger Zelazny, which takes place in a world where people can change bodies in an imitation of reincarnation.  When the god Brahma is murdered, the goddess Kali is chosen to be promoted as the new Brahma; this requires her to switch from her female body (giving up the ability to have children the female way) to a male one.

Comment: Not having read it - is it required to be male to be Brahma, or is it required to give up your reproductive capability? E.g. could the old Brahma have kids?

Comment: @AzorAhai--hehim: Brahma is required to be male.  No restrictions on reproductive capability are ever mentioned.  Brahma probably could have kids, but there's very little mention of such things among the gods.

Comment: Even before Durga/Kali/whatever-her-real-name-was became Brahma, the “original” Brahma had also switched sexes to become Brahma.

Comment: @jwodder Funny, considering how important that is in other mythologies.

Answer (score 8):

If technologically-enforced virginity counts (it's not technically sterility, but it's sufficient to prevent having sex in the first place) then you could consider [*The Spell Sword*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?5367) (**1974**) by Marion Zimmer Bradley.

The Keeper of a *laran*-matrix Tower (a psychic/magi-technical organization) is bound through the laran matrix to virginity, to the point that the laran will strike down anyone who tries to have sex with the Keeper.  This is mentioned in *The Spell Sword*, and fully shown in the sequel [*The Forbidden Tower*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1919).

These "old ways" of binding a Keeper are [described by Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Forbidden_Tower) as "neutering" so I think it's close enough to be worth considering as a fit for the question.

Comment: Mentioned already in "The Bloody Sun", which was published in 1964.

Comment: And Callina and Ashara are Keepers, in The Sword of Aldones, first published in 1962.  I am not sure if Keepers are mentioned in The Planet Savers, which I think was first published in 1958.

Comment: "neutering", or being made "emmasca", was a surgical procedure (done by matrix  I believe), which rendered the woman most definitely sterile.  The training, without neutering, was intense psychological conditioning and enforced isolation, separating the Keeper physically and emotionally from others.  In earlier times I believe they were pledged for life to this way.  So they were not physiologically sterilized, but pledged virgins who were so psychologically conditioned, and protected by convention, to be almost as close as makes no difference.

Answer (score 6):

[Interview with the Vampire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interview_with_the_Vampire) is a book from 1976. It starts a series called The Vampire Chronicles, in which ["vampirization" causes all of a person's bodily processes to cease:](https://vampirechronicles.fandom.com/wiki/Vampire)

> Upon their transformation, the newly born vampire will forever lose all natural bodily fluids (with the exception of blood) and their bodily functions will forever cease. It is because of this that vampires are unable to reproduce through pregnancy (...)

Comment: This seems to be the opposite: getting powers causes sterilization, rather than sterilization causing powers.

Comment: @Barmar Becoming a vampire has the hard requirement that you must die first - a vampire comes from a reanimated corpse. Since death causes sterilization, sterilization becomes a requisite to acquire vampire powers. Ergo, sterilization causes the powers.

Comment: That seems like a tenuous link. It seems more like a coincidental effect, not a prerequisite, and certainly not a *cause*.

Comment: This doesn't seem specific to gender though - a man who becomes a vampire also cannot father children.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman the question does not ask for gender specific answers. The example provided by the OP comes from a series where men (including *the Witcher*, the protagonist the series is named after) go through the same process and are also sterilised.

Comment: I'm not familiar with *The Witcher*, but both examples given are women (based on pronouns given at least), and the word "woman" is in the title of the question, and explicitly repeated in the last sentence of the OP.  Not sure how much more specific they could be...

Answer (score 5):

I'm sure there has to be an earlier example, but in Terry Pratchett's 1981 novel, *[Strata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strata_(novel))*, the treatment for immortality also removes your ability to have children. The 1988 novel *Cyteen* has a similar effect from their rejuvenation treatment. In between the two years, published in 1985, fantastic novel *With a Tangled Skein* by Piers Anthony has the female character rendered infertile during her time as an incarnation of Fate because her body is frozen in the state at which she gained the title and therefore a pregnancy cannot develop within her.